# Keep Getting ZeroDivisonError Whenever using module

Tags: python-3.x, module

So I am working on a problem which need me to get factors of a certain number. So as always I am using the module `%` in order to see if a number is divisible by a certain number and is equal to zero. But when ever I am trying to do this I keep getting an error saying `ZeroDivisionError` . I tried adding a block of code like this so python does not start counting from zero instead it starts to count from one `for potenial in range(number + 1):` But this does not seem to work.  Below is the rest of my code any help will be appreciated.

```
def Factors(number):
factors = []
for potenial in range(number + 1):
    if number % potenial == 0:
        factors.append(potenial)
    return factors
```

Comment: you'd need to `return factors` outside the `for` loop. your indentation is off anyway... (and this is a very inefficient way to get the factors of an integer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your for loop you are iterating from 0 (range() assumes starting number to be 0 if only 1 argument is given) up to "number". There is a ZeroDivisionError since you are trying to calculate number modulo 0 (number % 0) at the start of the for loop. When calculating the modulo, Python tries to divide number by 0 causing the ZeroDivisionError. Here is the corrected code (fixed the indentation):

```
def get_factors(number):
    factors = []
    for potential in range(1, number + 1):
        if number % potential == 0:
            factors.append(potential)
    return factors
```

However, there are betters ways of calculating factors. For example, you can iterate only up to sqrt(n) where n is the number and then calculate "factor pairs" e.g. if 3 is a factor of 15 then 15/3 which is 5 is also a factor of 15.
I encourage you to try an implement a more efficient algorithm.

Stylistic note: According to PEP 8, function names should be lowercase with words separated by underscores. Uppercase names generally indicate class definitions.